# ASP .NET MVC 3: How do I use a Generic view model in my EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, editorfor

I have a model.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public SubModel<float> prop1 { get; set; }
    public SubModel<int?> prop2 { get; set; }
    public SubModel<string> prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

And i have View.

```
@model MyModel

@{ 

    using (Html.BeginForm("Edited", "My", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.prop1,"SubModel")
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.prop2,"SubModel")
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.prop3,"SubModel")
    }
}
```

And i want to write Submodel.cshtml in EditorTemplates, but i can't write:

```
@model SubModel<T>
```

What should I do, besides create 3 Views for each type?

Answer (score 0):

Templates cannot be strongly typed open generics.

So you could use `dynamic`:

```
@model dynamic
```

or `object`:

```
@model object
```

but in both cases you will have to write ugly `ifs` inside in order to determine the correct type. For this reason I would recommend you to write different templates for each type and let the framework pick the correct template.

Comment: I tried to use `@model SubModel<dynamic>` and get `DateTime? prop4` to view, but i take exception: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'SubModel`1[System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SubModel`1[System.Object]'.